# How to call function inside ajaxComplete from document ready in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to execute function inside `.ajaxComplete()` from document ready.

```
$(function() {

      $(document).on('click', '.woof_radio_label', function(e) {
        if($(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term').is(':checked')) {
          $('.page-secondary-content').removeClass('open');
          $('.page-primary-content').removeClass('close');

          $(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term_reset').click();

          refineUrl();

        } else {
          $('.page-primary-content').addClass('close');
          $('.page-secondary-content, .bottom-content').addClass('open');
        }
      });

});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  function refineUrl() {
   console.log('it works');
  }
});
```

I am prompted with an error below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: refineUrl is not defined
>       at HTMLLabelElement. (scripts-custom.js?ver=4.9.7:15)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>       at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

When I click the class **woof_radio_label** it will trigger an ajax event(Product Filter), I want to call a function on ajaxComplete().

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: define `refineUrl` function in global scope, outside `ajaxComplete` method

Comment: you have error in this line ;  $(document).on('click', .woof_radio_label', function(e) {, remove the apostrophe after woof_radio_label

Comment: @vSugumar that is just a syntax error...

Comment: @Satpal Do you know how can i trigger it on ajaxcomplete?

Comment: `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
 refineUrl();
})` or simple `$(document).ajaxComplete(refineUrl)`

Comment: Do you know how can I call refineUrl() method only on click event on ajaxComplete? I'm NOT calling refineUrl() every ajaxComplete()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare function `refineUrl()` globally and then it can be called from anywhere. From `ajaxComplete` and from `document.ready` as well.

Like:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.woof_radio_label', function (e) {
        if ($(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term').is(':checked')) {
            $('.page-secondary-content').removeClass('open');
            $('.page-primary-content').removeClass('close');

            $(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term_reset').click();

            refineUrl();

        } else {
            $('.page-primary-content').addClass('close');
            $('.page-secondary-content, .bottom-content').addClass('open');
        }
    });

});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    //DO another stuff
});
function refineUrl() {
    console.log('it works');
}
```

Comment: This will call the function every ajaxcomplete as I have other links that have ajax calls.. Do you think this will only call refineUrl() on click event?

Comment: So as `refineUrl()` already defined then you can skip calling it in `ajaxComplete`.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue thanks to you. But I added j(document).ajaxStop(function() { refineUrl(); }); after the line $(this).siblings('.woof_radio_term_reset').click();

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `refineUrl()` at the top of your script to prevent from such type of errors like,

```
function refineUrl() {
    console.log('it works');
}
$(function(){
     .....
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   refineUrl(); 
});
```

Comment: This will call the function every ajaxcomplete as I have other links that have ajax calls.. Do you think this will only call refineUrl() on click event?